# installing MPI with VS on Win10

Tags: visual-studio, mpi, message-passing

I downloaded the MPI from this [MPI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100593) , but I have problem there is no `include` folder and `bin` does not contain all the files inside it !!
Then I'm trying with other version but the same problem!!
next I try with this website [Other MPI](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Server-Tools/HPC-Pack-MPI.shtml)to download MPI on windows but this message box showing to me during installation  "

```
    this install package contains both the 64bit and 32bit MPI runtime. 
Both Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable Package and Microsoft 
Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable package are needed prior to this installation
```

What should I do now? how can use mpi with visual studio?